# Вставка символа где-то в строку

Tags: javascript

**Допустим** есть строка с временем, например `1234`, по какой-то причине она не разделена, привычным нам, двоеточием.
Мы знаем, что двоеточие будет по середине, после первых двух символов.
Можно ли как-то вставить туда двоеточие средствами **JQ**?

В голову приходит только такой вариант:

```js
var str = '1234'; // Строка
// Далее как бы делим строку пополам
var strFirst = str.slice(0,-2); //Первые два символа
var strLast = str.slice(-2); // Последние два символа
// Ну а потом соединяем с двоеточием
str = strFirst+':'+strLast;
console.info(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Может есть не велосипед?

Comment: JQ тут не при чём от слова совсем.

Comment: ```'1234'.match(/.{2}/g).join(':')```

Comment: Эта строка - время?

Comment: `slice(0, -2)` - это не "первые 2 символа", а "все символы, кроме двух последних"

Comment: Кстати, а как быть со временем вида _001_ или _527_? Какой формат времени используется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
{ // Array.splice
  let a = '1234'.split('');
  a.splice(2, 0, ':');
  console.log('splice', a.join(''));
}

{ // regexp
  let a = '1234'.match(/\d{2}/g).join(':');
  console.log('regexp', a);
}

{
  // String.splice
  if (!String.prototype.splice) { // polyfill
    String.prototype.splice = function(index, del, ...chars) {
      return this.slice(0, index) + chars.join('') + this.slice(index + Math.abs(del));
    };
  }
  console.log('splice', '1234'.splice(2, 0, ':'));
  console.log('splice', '315'.splice(-2, 0, ':'));
}
```

Comment: Можно еще ```replace```'ом жахнуть: ```'1234'.replace(/(.{2})(.{2})/, '$1:$2')``` (_\d_ в регулярке не используется исходя из предположения, что все символы строки цифры, да и для простоты, хотя очевидно что правильней использовать именно проверку на соответствие числам).

Comment: Выберу Ваш ответ, т.к. больше способов реализовать задачу. Спасибо)

Comment: @gregzakharov, суть в том, что строка не обязательно из чисел, а символ между ними не обязательно `:`)

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вот так можно:

```js
function addColon(string) {
  if (string.length % 2 !== 0)
      return false;
   return string.substr(0, string.length/2) + ':' + string.substr(string.length/2);
}

console.log(addColon("123415"));
console.log(addColon("1234"));
```

Comment: Интересный вариант

Answer (score 1):

Хорошим вариантом будет использование библиотеки moment.js. + она позволит вам легко делать любые операции с временем и датой.(пригодится в любом проекте где есть монипуляции с датой и временем).

Вот Решение вашей задачи с использованием этой библиотеки:

```
const moment = require('moment');

const data = moment(1234, 'HHmm').format('HH:mm');
```

Comment: Использовать целую библиотеку ради одной функции - уже не хороший вариант.